# ex 24 Learn Ruby the hardway

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if someone can help me with the last line below, I am not sure how he calls the function using a string using %s and %d, I have searched online but cannot seem to find much.

```
start_point = start_point / 10
puts "We can also do that this way:"
puts "We'd have %s beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point) # <- this line
```

Comment: it's called "format string": https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25

Comment: "See Kernel::sprintf for details of the format string."

Comment: [printf format strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) exist in virtually any programming language (usually built-in, sometimes via external libraries). I'm surprised that you couldn't find any online resources.

Comment: Learn Ruby the Hard Way is considered to be a pretty bad translation of Learn Python the Hard Way, which in turn is considered to be a pretty bad tutorial. Do yourself a favor and find a better one!

Comment: thanks @JörgWMittag any recommendations?